# How to send header using PHP curl command line?

Tags: php, curl, header

I am using curl to post XML to a webservice. The code is below:

```
exec("/usr/bin/curl -s -m 120 -d  \"$xml\" $URL -L", $return_message_array, $return_number);
```

I want to add this custom header to it:

```
$headers = array(            
        "Content-type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8",
        "SOAPAction: http://loantree.com/webservices/InsertLead",
    );
```

I have tried:

```
exec("/usr/bin/curl -s -m 120 -H $headers -d  \"$xml\" $URL -L", $return_message_array, $return_number);
```

But that just returns the page I'm trying to post to. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Headers for [`curl`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) are set with the `-H` option, which can be used multiple times:

```
curl -H "Header-1: Value" -H "Header-2: Value" http://example.com
```

**Note:** If installed, PHP has a [curl library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). So you don't have to use `exec()`.

Comment: Great. Welcome to StackOverflow.