# cURL command line to send a file to a website directory using FTP

Tags: php, curl, command-line, easyphp

I have a website hosted in localhost. I'm using as a web server "EasyPHP".

I need to use a command line by **cURL** to send a file to a directory of the website.

Let's suppose that the **URL** of the website is :

```
localhost/testing_curl
```

And that "some_package.zip" is under the **local directory** :

```
C:\testing
```

So I need to make this **command line** work from MS-dos terminal :

```
curl -T some_package.zip localhost/test_curl/new_package_name.zip
```

And this :

```
curl -T some_package.zip http://localhost/test_curl/new_package_name.zip
```

I checked the configuration file **php.ini** and I un-commented this :

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

Then I restarted EasyPHP. But this didn't help.

I keep get this error message :

```
  The PUT
  method is not allowed for the requested URL.
```

under this error code :

```
  Error 405
```

**For info :** This worked for me to send a header :
[How to send header using PHP curl command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272900/how-to-send-header-using-php-curl-command-line#answer-13273074)

Comment: Did you install CURL separately rather than as PHP extension with EasyPHP?

Comment: Well, I have curl.exe under this directory : C:\Program Files\curl_733_0 and I added it to "Path".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here what I've done to resolve the problem :

1. Control Panel > Security Center > Firewall > Exception > Add port. Then I added two ports :

   Name : FTP Server
   Value : 21

   Name : FTP-Data
   Value : 20
2. I installed FileZilla Server : [here](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server)
3. FileZilla > Edit > Users > Add . Then I added a new user with password.
4. I shared these folders to the user I've created :

   **Only read right** : C:\Program Files\EasyPHP 3.0\www

   **Full right** (and absolutely "write" right) : C:\Program Files\EasyPHP 3.0\www\test_curl
5. I changed the curl command line to this (replace the variables by the right value):

   `curl --user %user_name%:%password% --ftp-create-dirs -T some_package.zip ftp://localhost/test_curl/new_package_name.zip`